# Carousel bootstrap c fade-эффектом

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap, css-animation

Здравствуйте!  Нашел в сети только один пример нормально работающей bootstrap карусели с эффектом fade. Автор предлагает решить его с помощью css-файла следующего содержания:

```
/* Fade Slider CSS */
.carousel .item {
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out opacity;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out opacity;
  -o-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out opacity;
  transition: 0.7s ease-in-out opacity;
  left: 0 !important;
}
.carousel .next.left,
.carousel .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel .active.left,
.carousel .active.right {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}      
.carousel .carousel-control {
  z-index: 1000;
  outline:none;
}
```

[Ссылка на страницу с решением](https://pro-cod.ru/kak-ustanovit-slajder-slider-bootstrap-3-0.html)
Пример работает верно. Но автор, насколько я понял, внес какие-то правки в bootstrap файлы. Об этом он сам не сообщает. Пример работает только с его файлом bootstrap.min.css.

В остальных найденных решениях, анимация включает "слепой" белый кадр, то есть в какой-то момент на экране присутствует только один кадр с прозрачностью (opacity) менее 1.

Не подскажет ли кто правильное решение с прозрачным исходным кодом. Спасибо. С уважением, Николай

Answer (score 0):

Понятно что carusel slide меняем на carusel fade.
А далее только наш файл css

```
.carousel.fade {
    opacity: 1;

}
.carousel.fade .item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
} 
.carousel.fade .item.active {
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Я не глянул исходный в вопросе. Изв. Все работает, все норм. Ручками только что сделал и затетсил